# Wordpress : cannot submit a backslash in article - backtick added to SQL Server Query

Tags: sql-server, wordpress, backslash

I know nothing of Wordpress.
I suspect that I may need to update this question with more info.
Please inform what I can check and I will revert and update.

We are using Wordpress as an internal Wiki.

An article will not post if there is a backslash in the article. It will just save the article as "auto-draft" but it will then clear your submission page and all your work will be done .

You can use a forward slash, but when a backslash is entered, all is lost.

I know that frontier press is used. I have disabled all plugins except frontier (need frontier to post), and it is definitely something to do with frontier.

I used SQL Server Profiler. When there is a backslash, the SQL parameters incorrectly get enclosed by a  ` (grave accent / backtick) character. This is what is causing the problem

[image]

How do I get rid of the backtick?
Is it Wordpress that processes the SQL or Frontier?
Could I report this supposed bug somewhere?
Would a plugin be possible or does a plugin exist already?

Comment: You mean backslash in the body? Should not be issue..

Comment: Yes backslash in the body. It should def not be the issue yes. I do not know where to start looking.

Comment: Looks like something else in your setup is doing this. as I just tested it on new WP site, and it posted just fine. I posted this "sadfasd \as nasfsafsdfk \ jasdfjlsakd fs\ asdflkj sdf\ sadlkfjsl af \ safklasdjf" If you have different sample to test, i can test for you.. could be some plugin or theme custom filter trying to filter the body and killing the content in the process..?

Comment: What version of Wordpress are you running? Have you tried upgrading to the latest?

Comment: Using 4.5.3 - latest version as of date is 4.7.3.

Comment: IIRC Wordpress is sort-of geared toward using MySQL as a storage backend. Running it against SQL Server may cause bugs to crop up that aren't present when it's talking to MySQL/MariaDB.